# How do I create a new branch in git?

Tags: git, branch

I have cloned a git repository and I would like to switch to a particular branch from the following list (e.g. branch1, branch2, branch3)

Should I have to say git fetch origin branch2?

How do I know that I have switched to this particular branch on my local repository?

How do I switch to say 'branch3' from 'branch2'?

Comment: Read and work through *any* git tutorial. It will be years until you will actually encounter a situation where you might need to post a question about git because all questions you have right now have already been asked and answered.

Comment: see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `git branch` to see what branches exist locally and which branch you are on. Then run `git checkout <branch name>` to move to a new branch. To create a new branch you can also run `git checkout -b <new branch name>`